# How Can I Update My Web Site Automaticlly EveryDay?

Tags: web

The tasks I do manually for updating my web site:

1. Stop IIS 7
2. Copy source files from a folder to the virtual directory of my web site
3. Start IIS 7

Comment: via using cron? see http://cronw.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Grammar Note: Marketing Caps (Aka Capping Every Word In The Damned Sentence Like This) Is A Pain To Read.  Stop It.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to approach this, but here is one way.

I am assuming you don't want every single file in your source repository to exist on your destination server. The best way to reliably extract what you need from your source on a regular basis is through a build file. Two options for achieving this are nant and msbuild.

Once you have the set of files you want to deploy, you now need a way to distribute them to your destination server & to stop and start IIS. Again, there are options, but I would personally recommend powershell (with the IIS snapin) for this.

If you want this to happen regularly, consider a batch file executed by some timer, such as a scheduled task, or even better, a CI solution such as TeamCity.

For a full rundown, there are examples within my [PowerUp](http://github.com/affinityid/powerup) project that does this.

Answer (score 0):

It depends where you are updating from, but you could have a your virtual directory pointing to a local read-only working copy of your source code and create a task that every day runs a batch file/powershell script/etc. that would update that working copy (via a svn update, git pull etc.)

That supposes that you have a branch that always contains the latest releasable code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a batch file with the following content:

1. Stop WWW publishing service
2. Delete your old files
3. Copy the new files
4. Start WWW publishing service

You can start/stop services like this:

```
net stop "World Wide Web Publishing Service"
```

When you have your batch file you can create a task in the Task Scheduler that calls your batch in a regular time interval (e.g. each day).